# Is it possible to use a Wii Extension controller on a PC without a Wiimote?

Tags: nintendo-wii, controllers

Just today I bought this Wii extension controller with the intent of using it on my PC, since the box says that a USB port is used for the wireless emitter.

[image: http://www.worten.pt/04403021_52575.jpg.image?size=240x200&TV=0&sku=04403021]

Unfortunately that wasn't the case; the wireless emitter only has one port that apparently only connects to a Wiimote (which I don't own). Is there a way of connecting this controller to a computer? Maybe a adapter between the extension port and a USB one?

I've tried to see if it uses Bluetooth, I don't think it does.

Comment: I'm going to go on a limb here and say it probably won't work. If it's wireless, it's probably going to be some kind of proprietary signal, and it's going to link up to a Wii controller which passes on the commands. Sorry. If it uses Bluetooth, you *might* be able to use GlovePIE, but it's going to be harder than usual without an actual Wii controller.

Comment: @Arda - you can connect a Wii Remote to a PC via Bluetooth. It's a standard Bluetooth device with nothing special to tie it to the Wii.

Comment: @ChrisF I know, but this device is meant to be connected *to* a Wii Remote, not directly to the Wii. What I believe the OP is trying to do is connect it up without a Wiimote.

Comment: @Arda - sorry - misinterpreted your comment.

Answer (score 2):

The Wii controller extension port uses an [I²C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-Integrated_Circuit) connection with a proprietary but simple protocol. Many people have reverse engineered it and used the controllers in electronics projects, and [according-to-Google](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=wii+classic+controller+to+pc) there is at least one [commercial product, by “Mayflash”,](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003711698) that adapts Classic Controllers (i.e. what you have) to being standard USB HID devices.

Answer (score 2):

You could buy [this adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0089O4EB0) if your remote came with a reciever to plug into the wiimote. It is used to connect a normal wii classic controller to a pc, so as long as your remote has something that is supposed to plug into the wiimote, this should work for you.